# To execute dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement dynamically

Tags: oracle, database

The requirement is as follows:

Through an Oracle Apex application I need to drop a user/schema in another Oracle database. i.e., drop user remotely using an Oracle Apex application.

Currently, I am using the below procedure for this task. But, as there are many remote databases, so, I would like to know is there a way to make this dynamic, i.e., to pass the DB link name to `DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT` dynamically. So, that the user will pass the user name and the database name and based on the database name the procedure will connect to the correct database/DB link and drop the given user. Please let me know if there is any other way to accomplish this task.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
    PROCEDURE drop_user_proc( 
    p_username VARCHAR2, 
    p_databasename VARCHAR2) 
IS 
    ddl_stmt VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN 
    IF p_databasename = ‘REMOTEDB1’ THEN 
        ddl_stmt := 'DROP USER '||p_username||' CASCADE'; 
        dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@remotedb1(ddl_stmt); 
END IF; 
END drop_user_proc;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
    PROCEDURE drop_user_proc( 
    p_username VARCHAR2, 
    p_databasename VARCHAR2) 
IS 
    ddl_stmt VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN 
    ddl_stmt := 'DROP USER '||p_username||' CASCADE'; 
    execute immediate 'begin dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@' || p_databasename || '(:ddl_stmt);  end;' using ddl_stmt;
END drop_user_proc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass the name of the database link to the `dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement` procedure.  You can, though, use dynamic SQL to invoke the procedure.  Something like (untested-- I don't have a database with a database link handy to test with at the moment)

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@' || p_dblink ||
                  '(''' || ddl_stmt || '''); END;';
```